# Is there a faster way to trim the tail of each element to be 15 characters

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I have a vector `A` with over 60 thousand elements.

```
Input 
head(A, n=10) = 
"ENSG00000000003.15" "ENSG00000000005.6"  "ENSG00000000419.13"
"ENSG00000000457.14" "ENSG00000000460.17" "ENSG00000000938.13"
"ENSG00000000971.16" "ENSG00000001036.14" "ENSG00000001084.13"
"ENSG00000001167.14" "ENSG00000002586.20_PAR_Y"
```

I want to trim the tails so that `nchar(a) = 15`

```
Output
head(A, n = 10) = 
"ENSG00000000003" "ENSG00000000005"  "ENSG00000000419"
"ENSG00000000457" "ENSG00000000460" "ENSG00000000938"
"ENSG00000000971" "ENSG00000001036" "ENSG00000001084"
"ENSG00000001167" "ENSG00000002586"
```

I could try using gsub to tackle this but I need to be careful not to cut off anything before the `.` and I'm not great at regex, so I've opted to use a while loop.

```
for(a in A){
while(nchar(a)>15){ 
AA= substr(A, 1, nchar(a) -1}
}
```

This is obviously not ideal as it takes a long time to run. Does anyone see an alternative?

Comment: `substr(A, 1, 15)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the part of the string before the point you can use `gsub`:

```r
gsub("\\..*", "", A)
```

If you need the first 15 characters you can use `substr`:

```r
substr(A, 1, 15)
```